# Caracteres raros al decodificar cadena en Base64

Tags: php, c#, array, base64

Buenas, llevo varios días intentando pasar una cadena en base64 a algo atendible, os explico que he probado para ver que solución puedo darle.

Primero de todo uso PHP, la cadena esta codifica en C# con `Convert.Tobase64String()`

1. Paso la cadena `"AAECAQcGqga5sgKsuwLTwwKZxwKixwIMS5EDogSRBv8HsgiCrQLSrgL+vAKhwgK8wwLKwwIA"`
   por `base64_decode()`
2. Me sale un resultado como este `"�����������K�������Ү��������"`
3. Pensado es so caracteres ASCII realizo el siguiente procedimiento

   ```
   $a = base64_decode($base64);
   $b = array();
   foreach(str_split($a) as $c)
   $b[] = bindec(sprintf("%08b", ord($c)));
   ```

Sale un array con unos números pero que deberían de corresponder con una id de una lista. Cosa que no lo hacen.

El código en C# no puedo postularlo por motivos de confidencialidad, pero lo que sí puedo decir es que el contenido es un array de Byte.

Comment: quieres decodificarlo en PHP me paso algo parecido, te puedo colocar el codigo en PHP

Comment: Usando [http://decodebase64.com/](http://decodebase64.com/) para decodificar el base64 que colocas en tu pregunta me retorna caracteres extraños; ¿el valro antes de ser convertido a base64 sufre otro proceso, pasa lo mismo con otros datos codificados en base64?

Comment: Seria bueno que nos de un ejemplo mínimo verificable. Si no sabemos cuál es el valor inicial, es muy difícil saber cómo se está codificando para llegar a ese valor.

Comment: ¿Probaste con la función [`unpack`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack) de php?. Los códigos del formato están en la documentación de la función [`pack`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php).

Answer (score 0):

tuve este problema en PHP por alguna razon no borraba esos caracteres , modifique la funcion a la siguiente:
suponiendo que tu resultado es el este :

```
$var = "�����������K�������Ү��������";
```

y tenemos esta funcion:

```
function desencriptar($valor_encriptado) {
          $utf8 = array(
            '/[áàâãªä]/u'   =>   'a',
            '/[ÁÀÂÃÄ]/u'    =>   'A',
            '/[ÍÌÎÏ]/u'     =>   'I',
            '/[íìîï]/u'     =>   'i',
            '/[éèêë]/u'     =>   'e',
            '/[ÉÈÊË]/u'     =>   'E',
            '/[óòôõºö]/u'   =>   'o',
            '/[ÓÒÔÕÖ]/u'    =>   'O',
            '/[úùûü]/u'     =>   'u',
            '/[ÚÙÛÜ]/u'     =>   'U',
            '/ç/'           =>   'c',
            '/Ç/'           =>   'C',
            '/ñ/'           =>   'n',
            '/Ñ/'           =>   'N',
            '/–/'           =>   '-', // UTF-8 hyphen to "normal" hyphen
            '/[’‘‹›‚]/u'    =>   ' ', // Literally a single quote
            '/[“”«»„]/u'    =>   ' ', // Double quote
            '/ /'           =>   ' ', // nonbreaking space (equiv. to 0x160)
        '/[^a-zA-Z0-9-+#=\/?\'\s]/' => ''
        );
        return preg_replace(array_keys($utf8), array_values($utf8), $valor_encriptado );     
    }
```

limpiamos la variable

```
var_dump(desencriptar($var));
```

Comment: No me reporta ningún resultado de vuelta. se queda en blanco

Comment: estas usando md_decrypt?

Comment: voy a modificar esta funcion elimina los caracteres especiales como podras observar

Comment: por favor ya modifique espero que esta si te funcione cheque a ver

Comment: Sigue igual me sale como Null, El proceso anterior es un Array de Byte En c# y pasan eso a Base64, con la función Tobase64String de c#

Comment: �����������K�������Ү�������� este es el resultado que me da del Base64_decode

Comment: probe y me funciono

Comment: una vez retornado ese valor usa la funcion desencriptar() , la cadena quedara como la deseas

Comment: Es lo que hago y me devuelve Null

Comment: te da algun error por que puede ser error de version de PHP

Comment: probe el siguiente codigo sin problemas https://pastebin.com/zF7ThyJ7 pruebalos separados

Comment: Probar con base64_decode("AAECAQcGqga5sgKsuwLTwwKZxwKixwIMS5EDogSRBv8HsgiCrQLSrgL+vAKhwgK8wwLKwwIA") y el resultado lo pasais por esa función da NULL

Comment: tu error es otro, tu cadena esta encriptada con otro idioma al intentar desencriptarla encriptarla te da un error como "Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid UTF-8 string at offset " trata de recibir una cadena utf-8

Comment: un ejemplo `byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("abcdef==");
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(base64);` en .net lo recibe PHP y por defecto su idioma es UTF-8

Comment: Pero no me sale .net necesito sacarlo en PHP

Comment: el detalles es que el codigo que recibe el PHP no tienen el Encoding UTF-8, tiene otro idioma y por eso no lo puedes decodificar bien averigua con que encoding se esta guardando el string en el otro lado del codigo para del lado de PHP hagas un setLocale

Comment: me puedes decir la palabra que estas decodificando? mira esta pagina https://www.base64decode.org/ copia la palabra y genera  el encode y funciona el codigo, el error es codificacion de donde se guarda el encode y donde lo decodifica no es el mismo

Comment: No es un palabra, lo comente arriba es un array de byte en C#

Comment: Se que necesitas sacarlo en PHP pero si la codificación es diferente no lo vas a lograr, intenta codificar el byte a utf8 luego lo envías y no tendrás problemas